# binding a angular reactive form FormControl to a dynamic value

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form instantiated using FormBuilder.  I would like to use this form for updating or adding a new employee.  I am trying to add an expression to the formBuilder constructor that checks to see whether there is a currently selected employee and if there is use one of that employee's interface fields as the value on the form and if there's no current selected employee have a empty string as the value of the specific FormControl.

what i've tried:

```
'EMP_NM': [this.selectedEmp ? this.selectedEmp.EMP_NM : '',  Validators.required],
```

and then in my editEmployee function:

```
editCashier(employee: IEmployee) {    
    this.selectedEmp = employee;      
    this.empForm.reset();     
    console.log(this.selectedEmp.EMP_NM);
}
```

When I do this the value shown on the EMP_NM input field in the HTML doesn't get updated.  i've tried setting a setTimeout() in my editEmployee function but that didn't work either.  Any idea what might be going wrong here?

I initialize the empForm in my conponent's constructor using formBuilder's group function.  Would it help if I moved that to a different function and then call that function everytime the editEmployee function is called to re-initialize the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can update it with patchValue or setValue:

```
this.empForm['controls']['employee'].patchValue(employee);
```

Have no clue if it's a nested control but you can go more layers down.

Comment: That doesn't seem very practical given that I have about 30 different form controls in that form...  Is there no way to bind the form to a employee if that employee exists and otherwise have all controls initialized with empty values?

Comment: Then you need something with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourNewFOrmValues).map((key: string) => { // the keys are your controls`. I use form array for this it's easier to loop over and set the value.